# Ball not smooth on ramp?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I want a ball to go up a ramp it goes in "shocks". Here is a GIF: https://gyazo.com/ad9d3d81893ceec6fa36989e947dfdaa . I am not sure if you can see it well on the GIF, but the ball doesn't roll smoothly on the ramp. On flat cubes it rolls smoothly. Does this have anything to do with colliders? Here is a screenshot with more info about the objects: http://prntscr.com/9ymhh9 .

Sidenote: Ball goes at 0.18f speed.

This is the script for moving the ball:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveStraight : MonoBehaviour
{
public float MovementSpeed;

void Start()
{
    SceneManager.currentSpeed = 0.08f;
}

void Update () {
    MovementSpeed = SceneManager.currentSpeed;
    transform.position -= new Vector3(MovementSpeed, 0, 0);
}
}
```

I also have these 2 scripts copied from a tutorial, I was planning on removing them and making one decent script.

```
function Update (){

if(Input.GetKey("left"))

{



transform.position.z -= 0.06;

}
}
```

AND

```
function Update (){

if(Input.GetKey("right"))

{

transform.position.z += 0.06;

}
}
```

Comment: Include your code.  Without being able to see how you're moving the ball it makes it hard to know what is wrong.

Comment: Another thought: maybe it's just an issue of the shadow-rendering and the ball is actually, in fact, rolling smoothly?

Comment: Try attaching Physics Material to the ball and/or slope collider with zero bounciness.

Comment: You're just moving the position of the object backwards on the x-axis by `MovementSpeed`, where does this account for going *up* the ramp? Let you handl the physics component that? Also, since your displacing your object in `Update()`, this is called *every frame*, so at 60FPS you get 60 displacements by a constant amount (`MovementSpeed`), as a result, you move faster when the game runs at a faster FPS rate and slower at lower FPS rates. You must multiply with `Time.deltaTime` to make this FPS-independent. Also, there are 2 other Scripts attached to that object which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I added the script in my question. Physic Material does nothing (if I do it correctly ofcourse: http://prntscr.com/9yms4d)

Comment: How could I add the time.deltaTime in my script? I have no idea where to put it.

Comment: Go look at [the Roll-A-Ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player?playlist=17141), try it's method of movement by using `.AddForce()` to a `Rigidbody` attached to the `GameObject`. If your camera starts spinning wildly go look at the "Moving the Camera" lession from the same tutorial on how to fix it.

Comment: Basically you want to move the ball using physics. It will be difficult to handle slopes of various angle using transform.

Comment: Get rid of all three scripts, since they're really buggy (FPS-dependent, btw. to make them independent you would do a `transfor.position += Time.deltaTime * new Vector3(MovementSpeed, 0,0)`), you want to the ball movement using the physics component, the script in the linked Roll-A-Ball tutorial at 12:47 is what you need (maybe with the force also acting in `Vector3.up` direction)

Comment: I will follow the tutorial and see if it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it does work you should either delete your question or create an answer and mark it as accepted once the two day wait limit is up.